# Tablesorter filter

Tags: jquery, filter, tablesorter

I'm using Tablesorter 2.9.1 with the Pager plugin. Everything works as it should.

I'd like to filter rows via a select menu according to classes applied to cells. For example, if a user selects 'show only *blue* widgets, all rows except for rows with a cell with class="blue" will be displayed.

Is this already available in any available plugins/widgets?

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question, maybe you want to use the `filter-onlyAvail` class name for a column?

Check out [this demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-custom.html), specifically the "Discount" column which has that class name applied (see the accordion pane):

```
<th class="filter-select filter-onlyAvail">Discount</th>
```

So, when a filter is selected in the first column, like `Aaron`, the "Discount" column will only show the available choices in its dropdown.

This option was added in version 2.10.1, so you will have to update the plugin.

Comment: Ok, I'll upgrade to 2.10.1. My comfort-level, with js doesn't go much beyond using Twitter bootstrap scripts, so my question is: will I be able to add the select menu outside of the table? I'd like it just above my table, to help make it stand out a bit.

Comment: @MattyPantaloons Yes, you can add a select menu, input, buttons or whatever outside of the table and bind them to search the table. Please see the docs for the [`getFilters`](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#getfilters) and [`setFilters`](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#setfilters) methods.